# Access model field from other model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have three models i need to access model 1 field from model 3

```
class Event(models.Model):
    custom_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')

class SubEvent(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(
    'Event',
    related_name='events',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

class Notice(models.Model)
      event = models.ForeignKey('Event', related_name='notices', 
                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to access SubEvent model data from Notice model is that possible?

Comment: There is no direct relation between Notice --> Subevent i have relation from Notice -- > Event --> SubEvent

Comment: There could be multiple related SubEvents, do you want to access a queryset/list of all related objects?

Comment: @IainShelvington can u post the query for both i will use whatever works best for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Exactly how depends on which SubEvent you want, but I presume you follow the foreign key from `notice` to `event` from where you have access to its (potentially multiple) `events`. So you might query

```
self.event.events.filter(
    # criteria to identify  particular SubEvents
    ...)
```

or just

```
self.event.events.all()
```

or fetch one, such as the latest:

```
latest_subevent = self.event.events.latest()
```

Comment: I need to query this in terminal this doesn't work in terminal right?

Comment: Can u put this into query filtering with model? actually filter would do the work in my case

Comment: Should work in terminal. Error message should explain. Post here if you don't understand.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "query filtering with model". Yes, you can define a method of the  notice model (which is where my "self" comes from).